# How to store method attributes in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Dates
  ATTRS = {date_from: '', date_to: ''}

  def set_dates(ATTRS)
    @date_from = date_from
    @date_to   = date_to
  end

  def show_dates(ATTRS)
    p date_from
    p date_to
  end
end

Dates.new.set_dates(date_from: Time.current, date_to: Time.current)
#-:4: formal argument cannot be a constant
#  def set_dates(ATTRS)
#                     ^
#-:9: formal argument cannot be a constant
#  def show_dates(ATTRS)
```

**SO question is: Is it possible to store method attributes in variable ?**

Comment: change to `def set_dates(ATTRS)` to `def set_dates(**args)`. This is [keyword arguments](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/ss/Keyword-Arguments.htm).

Comment: you right, i totally forgot about it, thanks, issue the answer.

Comment: release my answer, I will down it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write your code as below using Ruby (`2.0.0 > =`) new *keyword rest argument(`**`)* operator :

```
class Dates
  def set_dates(**attr)
    @date_from,@date_to = attr.values_at(:date_from,:date_to)
  end

  def show_dates
    p @date_from
    p @date_to
  end
end
```

Comment: Where are the *keyword arguments* in your example?

Comment: The return value of Hash#values may be in arbitrary order. I think you  shouldn't make assumptions that the value associated with `:date_from` comes first.

Comment: @apneadiving I will down it.. wait

Comment: @Agis What `**attr` is doing then ?

Comment: You are confusing the *keywords arguments* feature introduced in Ruby 2.0 with just expanding a hash argument. You're just accepting a hash no matter its contents are and assume that it has the wanted keys. This is not what *keyword arguments* is about. See @Arie Shaw answer, his method will raise an error if the proper arguments aren't passed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new keyword arguments syntax in Ruby 2.0:

```
class Dates
  def set_dates(date_from: '', date_to: '')
    @date_from = date_from
    @date_to = date_to
  end
  def show_dates
    p @date_from
    p @date_to
  end
end
```

Or the hash arguments before Ruby 2.0:

```
class Dates
  ATTRS = {date_from: '', date_to: ''}
  def set_dates(attr)
    attr = ATTRS.merge(attr)
    @date_from = attr[:date_from]
    @date_to = attr[:date_to]
  end
  def show_dates
    p @date_from
    p @date_to
  end
end
```

For the `show_dates` method, I guess you meant showing the status of the `Dates` instance, so I made some modification to it.

Besides, in Ruby, variables started with capitalized letter are treated as constants, you cannot use it as formal arguments of the methods.